# "The user to send to could not be found" when using API, using an e-mail identifier

Tags: dwolla

for example this query:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"oauth_token": "...","pin": "....","destinationId": "reflector@dwolla.com","amount":"0.5","fundsSource":"..."}' \
https://www.dwolla.com/oauth/rest/transactions/send
```

returns the following error:

```
"Success":false,"Message":"The user to send to could not be found.","Response":null
```

I also tried with a confirmed user account. I can send money using a dwolla number ID, but when using an e-mail I see the error `The user to send to could not be found.`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the "destinationType" if "destinationId" is anything other than a Dwolla account key.

Possible values: 'Dwolla', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Email', 'Phone'
Defaults to: 'Dwolla'